# Javascript, displaying images for certain lengths of time, conditional on image index

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new at javascript, I'm trying to make it so that my images dispaly one after another for variable lengths of time, depending on if they index of the image is even or not. I want to show an image for 800 milliseconds if it has an even index and 200 milliseconds if it has an odd index. I've adopted this code from different places on the web. Could someone help me out?

```
<html>
<head>

<img src="htp://user.local/web/images/owl.png" alt="rotating image" width="400" height="300" id="rotate">    
<script>

(function() {

    var rotate = document.getElementById('rotate');

    var iDir = 'http://user.local/web/images/';

    var idx = 0;

    var imag = ['ball.png','owl.png','bee.png','nail.png'];

    var x

    var imagPres = 0;

    for (x in imag) {

        if (imag.indexOf(x) % 2 != 0) {

            imagPres = .2;

    } else if (imag.indexOf(x) % 2 == 0) {

        imagPres = .8;

    }

    var chImg = function() {

        rotate.src = iDir + imag[idx++];

};

setInterval(chImg, imagPres * 1000);

})();
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is not working? Have you inspected the console for errors?

Comment: @wahwahwah what happens is the page loads the first image and remains that way. nothing changes.

Comment: Try to use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Comment: @faadi I have attempted this, same behavior. and inspecting the element does not show anything strange. At least not that I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.
Then instead of the for loop, let the setTimeout function call the function `chImg` again.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="htp://user.local/web/images/owl.png" alt="rotating image" width="400" height="300" id="rotate">
<script>
    (function() {
        var rotate = document.getElementById('rotate');
        var iDir = 'http://user.local/web/images/';
        var idx = 0;
        var imag = ['ball.png','owl.png','bee.png','nail.png'];
        var imagPres = 0;
        var lengthInMilliseconds = 1000;
        var len = imag.length;

        var chImg = function () {
            imagPres = 0.8;
            if (idx % 2 == 0) {
                imagPres = .2;
            }
            idx = idx === len - 1 ? 0 : ++idx;
            rotate.src = iDir + imag[idx];
            setTimeout(chImg, imagPres * lengthInMilliseconds);
        };
        setTimeout(chImg, imagPres * lengthInMilliseconds);
        })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```